# Javascript Bokeh Plot not rendering in browser

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, bokeh

I am creating a Bokeh Plot, and passing the html code `script, div = components(plot)`

```
return render_template('results.html',the_div=div,the_script=script)
```

The script and div have been passed to the browser, but instead of seeing the plot it displays the html code.

[image: Not rendering Bokeh Plot]

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block html_attribs %} lang="en" charset="utf-8"{% endblock %}

{% block title %}  Results {% endblock %}
{% block metas %}
</mysite/static/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.2.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.2.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.0.2.min.js"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
        {{ the_script }}
        {{ the_div }}
</div>
```

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?
-I've check that the bokeh version I'm using is 2.0.2
I am not familiar with javascript so I am assuming it could be a simple fix

The view from the browser console:
[image: Browser console]

Answer (score 3):

By default, all template parameters are escaped to prevent them from altering the DOM structure.
Since you do need to alter the DOM structure, you should just add `|save` to each variable:

```
{{ the_script|safe }}
{{ the_div|safe }}
```

More details: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I've added the |save to each variable, and now the html code is not rendered in the view, however my plot it not being rendered. I can see in the source code that the code is still there.. Is there something else that could be preventing the plot from being rendered?

Comment: Do you see anything in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Eugene I've just added the view from the console. I am new to this so I haven't had a change to research what any of that means yet.. But I can see that there is some kind of error.

Comment: I see that your BokehJS version is 2.0.2. But what is your Bokeh Python package's version? Seems like they're different. Also seems like you may be using `DataRange1d.callback` property - this property has been deprecated and later removed.

Comment: Thanks so much Eugene I updated the version to 1.3.4 and now it is displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Your console screenshot shows the problem. You are trying to load Bokeh JSON generated with Python Bokeh version 1.3.4 with BokehJS version 2.0.2 from CDN. This is not supported and will not work (the versions must match).

Comment: Great! I updated the version to 1.3.4 and now it is working! Thank you so much